# VB6 ADO command is inserting dates in American format instead of English

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado, datetime2

I have a VB6 legacy program that has been quietly converting Now() Date to American format ie 8/4/2013 is inserted into an Access database as 4 August 2013 but 23/3/2013 is fine. This has been happening since 2002 but nobody noticed until now. Most updates were done at the end of the month.

If I extract the Procedure and run it in a dummy program it works fine. But somewhere in the application code something is persuading ADO to try and convert the date.

It is done in a ADO Command and the date is set up as a DateTimeStamp parameter

```
eg
strSQL = "Insert into TSCDATA " _
                & " ( FID, FNAME, FPID, FCREATEDATE, FLNKEDTDATE, FSIZE)" _
                & " values ( ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? ) "
with mADOCmdInsert
    .Name = CMD_INSERT
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .ActiveConnection = m_conn
    .Prepared = False
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prID, adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prNAME, adChar, adParamInput, 16)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prFPID, adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prFCREATEDATE, adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prFLNKEDTDATE, adChar, adParamInput, 8)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter(prFSIZE, adChar, adParamInput, 8)    
End With
```

Elsewhere in the module:

```
dteNow = Now

With mADOCmdInsertScorpat
    .Parameters(prID).Value = lngId
    .Parameters(prNAME).Value = txtName
    .Parameters(prFPID).Value = VersionId
    .Parameters(prFCREATEDATE).Value = dteNow
    .Parameters(prFLNKEDTDATE).Value = ""
    .Parameters(prFSIZE).Value = txtSize

    .Execute lngRecsAffected
End With
```

Has anyone come across this before and now why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been unsuccessful in recreating your issue using the code provided in the question. I tried

- various combinations of Regional Settings in the Windows Control Panel: "English (Australia)", "English (Canada)", "English (United Kingdom)", "English (United States)", along with
- both OLEDB and ODBC connections, and
- I even back-dated the system clock in the virtual machine to April 2 to see if it was a `Now()` oddity.

In every case the ADO parameterized query inserted the correct date.

My suggestion would be to search the rest of the code for a rogue INSERT or UPDATE statement that passes a date literal directly to Jet. I'm quite certain that for any statement of the form...

```
INSERT INTO TSCDATA (FCCREATEDATE) VALUES (#2/04/2013 6:43:19 AM#)
```

...as produced by something like the following (in Australia)...

```
"INSERT INTO TSCDATA (FCCREATEDATE) VALUES (#" & CStr(Now) & "#)"
```

...Jet ***will always*** interpret the date as February 4 and not April 2, regardless of the Regional Settings for the date format.

Comment: I stepped through the code. Though other tables are updated as part of the transaction there are no obvious clues.

Like you I have tried to recreate the error outside of the application without success. 

Next week I will try and use dynamic SQL instead of an ADO Command to see if that works as a workaround. 

In the meantime the user will only be able to use the that part of the application after the 12th of the month. :-)